# Dynamic 1 to many db design -

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have 2 tables like: And I am using **mysql**.

**1. product**

[image]

**2. template**

[image]

Now 1 product can have multiple templates associated with it. Which I can achieve by creating a mapping table like:

**product_template**

[image]

Now based on some dynamic condition I need to select a template for the product for each request it is serving for:

**Condition like**

1. If request came from region-x then select template 2 for product 1.
2. If request came from region-y then select template 1 for product 1.

where I have multiple region in my DB . And to morrow if I want to add another condition that can be done by changes in DB only. Is there any design I should follow to open by DB design extendable.

Comment: Don't know if I understood corectly what you want, do you want not to write 100 conditions for 100 regions ? Why not make a table with template_id + region_id for mapping ?

Comment: @Cosmin at present the logic is for region_id only , but 2 morrow it will be region_id and user_id , so in that case I need to change the db again, so is there any way to handle this dynamically, otherwise  template_id + region_id is the last option and keep adding when new condition come

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the product_id + template_id table you can have a general connection table and add a type, for instance :

```
template_id  external_id  type
1            1            'product'
1            2            'product'
1            1            'user'
```

Then, you can add in this table what you want as type in the future. You just need to rewrite the joins accordingly to the type.